# Plotting a 2d vector on 3d axes in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, 3d, 2d

I have three vectors x,y,t. For each combination x,y,t there is a (u,v) value associated with it. How to plot this in matlab? Actually I'm trying to plot the solution of 2d hyperbolic equation
v<sub>t</sub> = A<sub>1</sub>v<sub>x</sub> + A<sub>2</sub>v<sub>y</sub> where A<sub>1</sub> and A<sub>2</sub> are 2*2 matrices and v is a 2*1 vector. I was trying scatter3 and quiver3 but being new to matlab I'm not able to represent the solution correctly. 
In the below code I have plot at only a particular time-level. How to show the complete solution in just one plot? Any help?

```
A1 = [5/3 2/3; 1/3 4/3];
A2 = [-1 -2; -1 0];
M = 10;
N = 40;
delta_x = 1/M;
delta_y = delta_x;
delta_t = 1/N;
x_points = 0:delta_x:1;
y_points = 0:delta_y:1;
t_points = 0:delta_t:1;

u = zeros(M+1,M+1,N+1,2);
for i=1:M+1,
    for j=1:M+1,
        u(i,j,1,1) = (sin(pi*x_points(i)))*sin(2*pi*y_points(j)) ;
        u(i,j,1,2) = cos(2*pi*x_points(i));
    end
end

for j=1:M+1,
    for t=1:N+1,
        u(M+1,j,t,1) = sin(2*t);
        u(M+1,j,t,2) = cos(2*t);
    end
end

for i=1:M+1
    for t=1:N+1
        u(i,1,t,1) = sin(2*t);
        u(i,M+1,t,2) = sin(5*t) ;
    end
end

Rx = delta_t/delta_x;
Ry = delta_t/delta_y;

for t=2:N+1
    v = zeros(M+1,M+1,2);
    for i=2:M,
        for j=2:M,
            A = [(u(i+1,j,t-1,1) - u(i-1,j,t-1,1)) ; (u(i+1,j,t-1,2) - u(i-1,j,t-1,2))];
            B = [(u(i+1,j,t-1,1) -2*u(i,j,t-1,1) +u(i-1,j,t-1,1)) ; (u(i+1,j,t-1,2) -2*u(i,j,t-1,2) +u(i-1,j,t-1,2))];
            C = [u(i,j,t-1,1) ; u(i,j,t-1,2)];
            v(i,j,:) = C + Rx*A1*A/2 + Rx*Rx*A1*A1*B/2;
        end
    end
    for i=2:M,
        for j=2:M,
            A = [(v(i,j+1,1) - v(i,j-1,1)) ; (v(i,j+1,2) - v(i,j-1,2)) ];
            B = [(v(i,j+1,1) - 2*v(i,j,1) +v(i,j-1,1)) ; (v(i,j+1,2) - 2*v(i,j,2) +v(i,j-1,2))];
            C = [v(i,j,1) ; v(i,j,2)];
            u(i,j,t,:) = C + Ry*A2*A/2 + Ry*Ry*A2*A2*B/2;
        end
    end
if j==2
    u(i,1,t,2) = u(i,2,t,2);
end
if j==M
    u(i,M+1,t,1) = u(i,M,t,1); 
end

if i==2
    u(1,j,t,:) = u(2,j,t,:) ;
end
end

time_level = 2;
quiver(x_points, y_points,  u(:,:,time_level,1), u(:,:,time_level,2))
```

Comment: Could you please add a code sample of what you have tried.

Comment: @nirvana-msu I have added the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can plot it in 3D, but personally I think it would be hard to make sense of.

There's a `quiver3` equivalent for your plotting function. `z`-axis in this case would be time (say, equally spaced), and z components of the vectors would be zero. Unlike 2D version of this function, it does not support passing in coordinate vectors, so you need to create the grid explicitly using `meshgrid`:

```
sz = size(u);
[X, Y, Z] = meshgrid(x_points, y_points, 1:sz(3));
quiver3(X, Y, Z, u(:,:,:,1), u(:,:,:,2), zeros(sz(1:3)));
```

You may also color each timescale differently by plotting them one at a time, but it's still hard to make sense of the results:

```
figure(); hold('all');
for z = 1:sz(3)
    [X, Y, Z] = meshgrid(x_points, y_points, z);
    quiver3(X, Y, Z, u(:,:,z,1), u(:,:,z,2), zeros([sz(1:2),1]));
end
```